# Pass rsh command password?

Tags: bash, unix, rsh

Trying to log into a server with rsh, even though I usually log into it with ssh.  Works perfect with ssh, but I don't want to enter my password every single time.

I guess I need to pass the rsh command a password since I tried the following...

```
rsh -l user@servername 
rsh -l user@servername -n
rsh -l user@servername echo "something"
```

...but got this error message

```
rcmd: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

How would I log into rsh and either bypass my password (i.e. which I can't get rid of at the moment) or pass it my password?

Comment: Rather than using passwordless `rsh` (which is horribly insecure), look into using `ssh-agent` so you can use passwordless `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to use rsh since it's less secure but this page should help you:

http://rajaseelan.com/2009/07/03/how-to-enable-passwordless-rsh-login-in-rhel5/